# How to $watch changes in array item but not the array itself

Tags: angularjs

For example I have

```
$scope.array = [{ foo: 'bar'}, { foo: 'bar2'}]
```

I want to watch this array such that

```
$scope.array.pop(); //$watch is not called
$scope.array[0].foo = 'newbar'; //$watch is called
$scope.array = [{ foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'anotherbar' }]; //$watch is not called
```

Is it possible to accomplish this with $scope.$watch?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to return the required value to watch:

```
$scope.$watch(function(scope) { return scope.array && scope.array[0].foo; }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // any action here
    }
);
```

if you need to observe more itens, you can to return another array with all foo's objects, for example.